# Good symbolic mathematics packages?

Tags: software-recommendation, mathematica

I recently moved from Mac OS X to Ubuntu, and I'd like to (as much as possible) only use free software on my new machine. As a theoretical ecologist, I used to  rely a lot on Mathematica, and even though there is a Linux version out there, I'd really rather use something free.

Some people have mentioned [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) and [sympy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/) (both are fine with me), but I'd really love to hear about other alternatives, and people's experiences with any of these packages.

Comment: Wrt Maxima, install wxmaxima. It is a GUI that is widely used: http://andrejv.github.io/wxmaxima/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_mathematics_software

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_analysis_software

there is pretty much everything you can get for free here.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any experience with any of them?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu ships with **python** (by default),and there are plenty of useful python packages available. You would find numpy and matplotlib very useful since you are coming from mathematica.